# ReferenceError: ‘PageMinimized’ is undefined - HealthAnalyzer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, health-analyzer

I have installed SharePoint 2016 RTM as a single server farm, I have just updated to the latest Updates (June 2018) and now when I navigate to the SharePoint Health Analyzer in Central Admin I get:

ReferenceError: ‘PageMinimized’ is undefined

*** UPDATE

This is happening on all listview pages

Any help appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the July 2018 update fixed the problem.

I cant be clear on the exact problem but I believe it was more related to the jump straight from RTM to June 2018, each update doesn't always contain all CU for all services and something was missing.

Possibly best to start RTM upgrade to Feature Pack 2 and work forward.

More enlightened suggestions welcome.